# Type Error in Python function

Tags: python, function, types, typeerror

I'm working a small program that calculates the trajectory of an object fired on certain planetary bodies, then plots them with Turtle graphics. Currently, I'm stuck on an issue with a Type Error that I can't seem to figure out.

So, here is the stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "MY FILEPATH", line 174, in <module> main()
File "MY FILEPATH", line 153, in main
    x1,y1 = xtoy(dist(velo,ang,grav),velo,ang,grav,i)
File "MY FILEPATH", line 66, in xtoy
    sety = int(dist*tan(ang)-(grav*dist**2)/(2*velo**2*cos*((cos(ang)))))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

and here is a pastebin of the code.

http://pastebin.com/aY0fhGEV

I am absolutely stumped, and have been wracking my brain for a week. Any help would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have `2 * cos`.  This is trying to multiply the number 2 times the function `cos`.  You need to take the cosine *of* something in the second part.  Perhaps you meant `2*cos(ang)*cos(ang)`?

Comment: @user1724602 The same goes for your own functions like `dist`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra * after the second to last `cos`, which treats it like a built-in instead of evaluating an argument.